# MySQL list all rows in one table excluding the ones already referenced by another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've spent some time tearing my hair out and combing the internet for help, but I'm not having much luck. I feel like I'm missing something obvious and I'm tired and annoyed lol

I have two tables. One is called RolesAndServices and one is called Roles. They look like this.

```
Roles
- ID
- Name

RolesAndServices
- ID
- JobID
- RoleID
- ClientID
- PeopleID
```

What I am attempting to achieve is something like this:

```
SELECT Roles.ID, Roles.Name FROM Roles, RolesAndServices WHERE
RolesAndServices.RoleID = Roles.ID AND NOT RolesAndServices.JobID = 1
```

The reason that does not work is because all the items in RolesAndServices (currently) have the JobID 1. Fair enough. So I get why that doesn't work.

What I am attempting to achieve is a list of all the items in Roles, **excluding** those Roles that are both

1. Present in the RolesAndServices table and
2. Have a JobID that is set to 1

Basically the end goal is to create a HTML select that will contain options for every role except those already set up for that job.

For example, say there are three roles in total:

1. Teacher
2. Student
3. Parent

If a job has already had the teacher role added to it, RolesAndServices has an entry with the roleid of teacher and the jobid of the job in question. When adding another role to that job, the available options should be

1. Student
2. Parent

I've tried a variety of join based queries as well to no avail. Selecting all the roles and then excluding those that have been used in rolesandservices is achieveable, I just stumble when limiting the exclusion to a particular job number.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Thank you to John Woo for the very quick response to my question - I've used his code to evaluate the available roles on a per job basis as I needed to, and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT  ID, Name
FROM    Roles ro
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  NULL
            FROM    RolesAndServices rs
            WHERE   ro.ID = rs.RoleID
                    AND rs.JobID = 1
        )
```